# How to create proper feedforward neural network with evolutionary algorithm

Tags: neural-network, evolutionary-algorithm

I've created a 2D game where you use map editor to place cars, obstacles and destination point where cars should go.

The idea is that these cars will be controlled by generation of feedforward neural networks. But I'm not sure how information should be represented in input layer and how exactly evolution should be like, so I'll explain my idea and it would be great to have advice on how to make this idea better especially if something will not work at all.

Input layer values:

1. Neurons in between (0,1) representing distance to the obstacle
2. Neuron in between (-1,1) representing the speed of car and its direction (-1 - max speed backwards, 0 - no speed, 0.5 - half of max speed forward)
3. Two neurons in between (-1,1) representing cos and sin (or 2*asin/Pi and 2*(acos-pi/2)/Pi) of vector from car to destination relative to some canvas (map) constant axis.

Output layer values:

1. Neuron between (-1,1) representing acceleration of car and its direction
2. Neuron between (-1,1) representing where and how fast car will turn

Looking at values, I'm thinking about using tanh function everywhere. But is this a good idea to use a single negative/positive value to determine a direction (as input or output)? Or is it a good idea to use two neurons to tell to a neural network where it should go (obviously can't tell with single value) and etc?

I imagine evolution itself to be be about switching some weight and bias values mostly between best networks (depending on fitness) and adding small random numbers to some weights and biases to mutate (where random number abs will depend on fitness in order to avoid destructive huge changes in good networks).

Comment: keep the net as small as possible, try CMA-ES from a library (no param tweaking), make sure initial weights lead to diverse behaviour/fitness

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have not used CMA-ES because the whole project is JS code, yet it was really useful for me in order to better understand what's going on. You've said that I should keep net as small as possible, I've been thinking on this and come to some interesting question:

Let's assume that size of network (or something else to evolve) is N, and size of population must be at least P to evolve it to the best condition (I think it's kinda wrong to say "at least", but let's just assume that). If i'll increase net size to N+K, then P must be increased to P^(1+K), is that right?